# Simplifying the following expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to simplify this expression shown in the input here http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=p((((1-p)%2Fp)%5E(k%2B1)-1)%2F(((1-p)%2Fp)%5E(a%2Bb)-1))%2B(1-p)((((1-p)%2Fp)%5E(k-1)-1)%2F(((1-p)%2Fp)%5E(a%2Bb)-1))

I would like it in the second alternate form that Wolfram shows. How would one simplify this?

In short, how do I go from this:

$$\frac{p\left(\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^{k+1}-1\right)}{\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^{a+b}-1}+\frac{\left(\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^{k-1}-1\right)\left(1-p\right)}{\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^{a+b}-1}$$

To this:

$$\frac{\left(\frac{1}{p}-1\right)^k-1}{\left(\frac{1}{p}-1\right)^{a+b}-1}$$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to include the formula in your post.

Comment: You mean what happens after this
$$\frac{\left(p^k-(1-p)^k\right) p^{a+b-k}}{p^{a+b}-(1-p)^{a+b}}$$

Answer (score 0):

We have: 
\begin{align}
\frac{p\left(\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^{k+1}-1\right)}{\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^{a+b}-1}+\frac{\left(\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^{k-1}-1\right)\left(1-p\right)}{\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^{a+b}-1} &=
\frac{\left(p^k-(1-p)^k\right) p^{a+b-k}}{p^{a+b}-(1-p)^{a+b}} \\
&=\frac{\Big(1-\Big(\frac{1-p}{p}\Big)^k\Big)p^{a+b}}{\Big(1-\Big(\frac{1-p}{p}\Big)^{a+b}\Big)p^{a+b}} \\
&=\frac{1-\Big(\frac{1-p}{p}\Big)^k}{1-\Big(\frac{1-p}{p}\Big)^{a+b}}\\
&=\frac{\left(\frac{1}{p}-1\right)^k-1}{\left(\frac{1}{p}-1\right)^{a+b}-1}
\end{align}

as desired.